# put  div and inside <td> tag

Tags: jquery

it's dynamic code and i have design issue with that

```
<td id="test" class="test1"></td>
<div id="WidgetButton" class="right">test</div> // that part of code making dyamic


  there is any way put that <div> has id WidgetButton and inside <td></td>
```

like that

```
<td id="test" class="test1">
<div id="WidgetButton" class="right">test</div>
</td>
```

plz suggest me how can i do it with jquery

thanks

Comment: may i know the reason ,why my question got 4 down vote?

Comment: plz add comment also when you down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both of them have `id`s, this is a trivial application of the [`jQuery` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) (usually aliased as `$`) and [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

```
$("#WidgetButton").appendTo("#test");
```

It's just as well they both have `id`s, too, because otherwise it would be tricky, since the markup is invalid and so browsers will relocate the `div` to where they *guess* it should go, so using structural selectors and relative traversal would be difficult. The `id` values trump that, thankfully.

Comment: @vikas: Good deal, glad that helped. I'd recommend taking some time to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com). It'll only take you an hour or two at most, and it saves you a huge amouht of time in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Since you only want to do this for div with id `WidgetButton`. Heres how

```
 $("#WidgetButton").appendTo("#test");
```

---

If you to remove all `divs` and put inside a `td`, it might prove to be dangerous. But you can do this like

```
$("div").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo("#test");
});
```

---

However, I will extremely recommend you narrow your selection to a particular group of divs like using class names or ids.

ClassName

```
$(".divswithclassname").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo("#test");
});
```

Certain Id

```
$("#idofdiv")..appendTo("#test");
```

Comment: i want to do only div has id WidgetButton